# data.table: Update multiple columns in a data.table with a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, data.table

How do I update multiple columns in a `data.table` with values from a matrix. Here is an MWE illustrating the issue I am facing:

```
library(data.table)
DT = data.table(expand.grid(1:3,1:3,1:3))
DF = expand.grid(1:3,1:3,1:3)
mat = matrix(seq(0, 80), 27, 3)
```

In a `data.frame` world I would go with this syntax:

```
DF[,2:ncol(DF)] = mat[,2:ncol(DF)] #Data frame approach
```

A similar take on `data.table` syntax yields multiple warnings with a very weird output.

```
DT[,2:ncol(DF) := mat[,2:ncol(DF)], with=FALSE] #Data table approach
```

This is obviously faulty - as the warnings indicates that the matrix was actually flattened. Warning messages:

```
1: In `[.data.table`(DT, , `:=`(2:ncol(DF), mat[, 2:ncol(DF)]), with = FALSE) :
  2 column matrix RHS of := will be treated as one vector
```

Comment: Note that `DT[,3:ncol(DT) - 1]` is an often made egregious error - you're subtracting 1 from every number in `(3:ncol(DT))`, not just `ncol(DT)` itself

Comment: I suggest going through the vignettes on the [Getting started](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) page. Especially the *Reference Semantics* vignette. The RHS of `:=` expects/needs a *list*. Coercion is unavoidable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to convert the RHS to a `list`, and an easy way to do that is to use `as.data.table`:

```
DT[, 2:ncol(DT) := as.data.table(mat[,2:ncol(DT)])]
```

`with` is not necessary here, as LHS is deduced to mean column numbers automatically.

Comment: I'm curious what you mean when you say this kind of assignment isn't *optimized*. Is assignment using the `:=` syntax normally optimized in a way that is not possible with this particular usage? Keep in mind I'm a bit of a data.table novice.

Comment: @bgoldst My post got edited so that line is no longer there, but I mean "optimized" in the non-technical sense of the word. `:=` was designed to be used where you have specific column names being assigned to and specific object names on the right. Something like `data[, c("Speed", "Time") := list(dt2$Distance/dt2$Time, dt2$Time)]`

Answer (score 3):

When assigning to multiple columns, the columns should be collected in a list:

```
idx <- 2:ncol(DT)
DT[,idx] <- lapply(idx, function(col) mat[,col])
```

This same syntax works for a data.frame. It's nonstandard in a data.table (where `set` and `:=` are idiomatic), but still has the benefit of modifying `DT` by reference, I think.

The idiomatic `:=` approach is:

```
DT[,(idx) := lapply(idx, function(col) mat[,col])]
```

Comment: So in a way we are falling back on `data.frame` syntax. Only that the items we are indexing on should be a list?

Comment: Or just `DT[,(idx) := data.table(mat[,idx])]`, no?

Comment: @sriramn Yeah. Though I'd advocate the `:=` version (that I just added to the answer), since it's idiomatic and therefore easier to read amidst other data.table code. See Arun's comment on your question for a good place to start.